# Get custom taxonomy on rest api

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

How can i get custom taxonomy of my custom post in response of

```
/Wpjson/wp/v2/postName
```

I have made one from the ACF and second from custom coding in WordPress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting custom taxonomy you can use following query.

```
query MyQuery {
  allWordpressAcfResource {
    nodes {
     acf {
      topics {
       name
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: But i need the rest route registered taxonomy